# Why is $\int_0^1|f(x)|\cos(2\pi x) dx$ not a norm when $\int_0^1|f(x)| (\cos(2\pi x))^2 dx$ is on vector space $C[0,1]$?

Tags: integration, vectors, normed-spaces

I found for any continuous function $z: [0,1] \to R^+$ with $z(x) = 0$ only on a finite set then $\int_0^1|f(x)|z(x) dx$  is a norm on $C[0,1]$. So my confusion lies in why  $\int_0^1|f(x)| (\cos(2\pi x))^2dx$ is a norm but $\int_0^1|f(x)|\cos(2\pi x) dx$ is not. With research I found that $\int_0^1|f(x)|\cos(2\pi x) dx$ is not a norm since $\Vert1\Vert = 0$ and that $\Vert f \Vert$ can be negative but I don't understand why this is not true for $\int_0^1|f(x)|\cos(2\pi x)^2dx$. I thought it may have to do with the theorem I provided at the start but I do not see why. I apologies if this is confusing and I will try to clarify if needed. Any help, links or explanation is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Observe that $z$ satisfies that $z(x) \geq 0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ with equality only for finitely many $x$, but is not true that $\cos(2\pi x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, e.g. $x=\tfrac12$. In other words, the theorem is not aplicable.

Comment: Did you try to verify the norm axioms for the first norm?

Comment: Did you stop to notice that $\cos^2$ is everywhere non-negative? (By the way, you have an important typo in the paragraph. You wrote $\cos(2\pi x)^2$, which is quite different from $(\cos 2\pi x)^2$.

Comment: @azif00  So with the x value you given as an example, this would result to -1 which fails the property?

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry for the typo. Also I did not notice that but given that I see it satisfies the theory making it applicable. In future reference I will be sure to be more observant

Comment: @fwd So can I say that if I let f be 0 then I am left with the integral of 0 from 1 to 0 which gives me 1 so I am left with ||1|| which is not equal to ||0|| and so f = 0 does not give me ||f|| = 0?